# Azure Pipeline's variables not showing in express server environment variables

Tags: azure, express, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines

### My Steps to Set Environment Variable

1. Go to Azure DevOps pipeline
2. Edit pipeline (azure-pipelines.yml)
3. Click Variables
4. Add `BUILD_ID` as variable

[image]

5. Add `BUILD_ID` under the `env` clause during install script

```
- script: npm install
  displayName: 'npm install'
  env:
    BUILD_ID: $(BUILD_ID)
```

6. In express server, use the environment variable by `process.env.BUILD_ID`

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(process.env.BUILD_ID));
```

### Result

Getting `undefined` as result.

### Question

Why pipeline variables not accessible in express server?
I'd like to use the [Azure predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) in my express server such as the `Build.BuildId` info.

[image]

### My full yml file

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'Download .env file'
  inputs:
    secureFile: '.env'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: $(Agent.TempDirectory)
    Contents: '**/.env'
    # TargetFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    TargetFolder: './server'

- script: |
    set
    cd server
    npm install
  displayName: 'npm install'
  env:
    BUILD_ID: $(BUILD_ID)

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'xxx'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'xxx'
    packageForLinux: './server'
    WebConfigParameters: '-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile run.cjs -appType node'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    DeploymentType: 'webDeploy'
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
```